# Edited questions

Tags: support, editing

English is not my native language and when I ask some question I make a lots of mistakes. Some time later I see that my question edited but I don't know where, since I don't exactly remember the text of my question. Is there a way to see this edits? This opportunity will help me improve my English and analyze my mistakes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just edited your question here to fix a small typo. You see my user card right left to yours:

[image: User cards]

The [5 secs ago](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3412/revisions)  (which will display a different time  when you read this) above my user name is clickable and leads you to

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3412/revisions

where you can see the change I made.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer!